# How do I connect to xenoverse

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse

I've made prerequisite quests and now the game explained what I can do online / offline. I still cannot find out how I toggle between connected to Xenoverse or not connected as right now, many features are turned off because I am "not connected".

How do I connect to xenoverse